# Why are event argument optional in anonymous functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events

I'm just trying to understand the logic behind this code:

```
window.onkeydown = function () {
    handler(event);
};
function handler(event)
{
    console.log(event.key); // this works!
}
```

Shouldn't the event handler be declared with the event argument included in the anonymous function? Like so:

```
window.onkeydown = function (event) {
    handler(event);
};
```

I understand that browsers automatically pass the event to the handler, but still I find it weird that assigning an anonymous function without arguments still works. Is this a normal behaviour?

Comment: Internet Explorer traditionally did *not* pass the `event` object as a parameter. Instead, it's a global variable that's updated when an event occurs. That was a horrible design decision but most browsers (Firefox excepted) now imitate that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are event argument optional in anonymous functions in Javascript?

They aren't, cross-browser. Microsoft had a *global* `event` that was set to the current event before calling handlers using their `attachEvent` (and `onxyz`) handlers. The DOM standard went another way: passing `event` as an argument.

Chrome and some other browsers do both, so that Microsoft-specific code works on them. But not all browsers do. Firefox doesn't, for instance, unless you set a special preference in your user preferences ([details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event)).

The key takeaway is: Use modern event handling (`addEventListener`, etc.), which is supported in all browsers other than IE8 and earlier, and declare the `event` parameter to  the function:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", handler);

// ...

function handler(event) {
    // ...
}
```

or (the function name is optional, but useful in error call stacks):

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function handler(event) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I actually tried the code on a fresh installed Firefox 71 and it also works! I guess they reenabled that global event by default in recent versions... Don't  really see the point, it seems messy and poor design...

Comment: @nrgribeiro - The point to the global? Agreed, the DOM standard's way is the way to go. But I guess Mozilla decided that they wanted to get rid of all those "why does this code work everywhere but Firefox?" complaints. :-) Or it's getting adopted as a standard, a lot of old legacy stuff is...